# Integrating Apache to tomcat servers using mod_jk

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-jk

We have an existing setup as below,

1 apache server and 2 tomcat servers in the backend , both the tomcat servers have same application and apache is integrated with these tomcat servers using mod_jk. Everything is working fine.

New requirement to use same apache server to integrate with another set of 2 tomcat servers
with different application.

My existing setup looks like below,

**Vhost file for app1**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  SSLEngine on
  ServerName server.domain.com
  ServerAlias *.domain.com
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^/hmc - [F]
  RewriteRule ^/hmc_junit - [F]
  RewriteRule ^/hac - [F]
  RewriteRule ^/hac_junit - [F]
  RewriteRule ^/rest - [F]
  RewriteRule ^/backoffice - [F]
  RewriteRule ^/admincockpit - [F]
  RewriteRule ^/cmscockpit - [F]

Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000;"
# Header always set X-Frame-Options DENY
Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https

LogLevel warn
ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

JkMount  app1/* loadbalancer
JkMount  /status node1
</VirtualHost>
```

**Vhost file for app2**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  SSLEngine on
  ServerName server.domain.com
  ServerAlias *.domain.com
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^/hmc - [F]
  RewriteRule ^/hmc_junit - [F]
  RewriteRule ^/hac - [F]
  RewriteRule ^/hac_junit - [F]
  RewriteRule ^/rest - [F]
  RewriteRule ^/backoffice - [F]
  RewriteRule ^/admincockpit - [F]
  RewriteRule ^/cmscockpit - [F]

Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000;"
# Header always set X-Frame-Options DENY
Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https

LogLevel warn
ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

JkMount  app2/* loadbalancer2
JkMount  /status node3
</VirtualHost>
```

**mod_jk.conf**

```
LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so

JkWorkersFile conf/workers.properties

JkLogFile logs/mod_jk.log

JkLogLevel info

JkLogStampFormat  "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y]"

JkOptions +ForwardKeySize -ForwardDirectories

JkRequestLogFormat "%w %V %T"

JkMount app1/* loadbalancer
JkMount app2/* loadbalancer2


JkShmFile logs/jk.shm

<Location /jkstatus/>
  JkMount status
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from all
</Location>
```

**workers.properties**

```
 #Define list of workers that will be used
 # for mapping requests
 workers.list=loadbalancer,loadbalancer2,status

 # Define Node1
 modify the host as your host IP or DNS name.
 workers.node1.port=8009
 workers.node1.host=tomcat1.domain.com
 workers.node1.type=ajp13
 workers.node1.ping_mode=A
 workers.node1.lbfactor=1

#Define Node2
modify the host as your host IP or DNS name.
workers.node2.port=8009
workers.node2.host=tomcat2.domain.com
workers.node2.type=ajp13
workers.node2.ping_mode=A
workers.node2.lbfactor=1

# Define Node3
# modify the host as your host IP or DNS name.
workers.node3.port=8009
workers.node3.host=tomcat3.domain.com
workers.node3.type=ajp13
workers.node3.ping_mode=A
workers.node3.lbfactor=1

# Define Node4
# modify the host as your host IP or DNS name.
workers.node4.port=8009
workers.node4.host=tomcat4.domain.com
workers.node4.type=ajp13
workers.node4.ping_mode=A
workers.node4.lbfactor=1

# Load-balancing behavior
workers.loadbalancer.type=lb
workers.loadbalancer.balance_workers=node1,node2
workers.loadbalancer.sticky_session=1

# Load-balancing behavior
workers.loadbalancer2.type=lb
workers.loadbalancer2.balance_workers=node3,node4
workers.loadbalancer2.sticky_session=1

# Status worker for managing load balancer
workers.status.type=status
```

But , to add 2 new tomcat serves (for second application) in apache . i've created another workers.properties file , modjk.conf and another vhost file .and tried restarting the apache and failed with below error. Apache is considering JkWorkersFile in second modjk.conf as duplicate.

How to fix this issue and use same apache for integrating different tomcat servers (diff apps) ?

Thank you in advance.

```
Sep 01 18:20:29 l6681t.sss.se.scania.com systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Sep 01 18:20:29 l6681t.sss.se.scania.com httpd[2743]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 6 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/qa02-modjk.conf:
Sep 01 18:20:29 l6681t.sss.se.scania.com httpd[2743]: JkWorkersFile only allowed once
Sep 01 18:20:29 l6681t.sss.se.scania.com systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 01 18:20:29 l6681t.sss.se.scania.com systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Sep 01 18:20:29 l6681t.sss.se.scania.com systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Sep 01 18:20:29 l6681t.sss.se.scania.com systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
```

Comment: If you have a `mod_jk.conf`, what is `qa02-modjk.conf` and what is the syntax error on line 6 of that file?

Comment: Hello @HatLess 
I created another modjk file qa02-modjk.conf for the second application which i was trying to configure .

line 6 of that file is below,

        JkWorkersFile conf/qa02-workers.properties

Comment: Then you have two worker files? You may need to disable the worker in one of the files if enabled in both,.

Comment: You can just put both load balancer definitions into one `workers.properties` file. Just make sure that the identifiers (the word after `workers.`) are distinct for the two sets.

Comment: Sure , I will try these options and update you . Think you..

Comment: Hello @PiotrP.Karwasz ,

I made the changes as per your suggestion , updated worker.properties and modjk files are below .

Comment: Hello @PiotrP.Karwasz,

Update the workers.properties file and mod_JK file in the question , also created another vhost fole for app2 with loadbalancer2 ,

Only app1 is working and the app2 towards node3 and node4 is not working . Can you please check and let me know if i am missing anything in the configs

Comment: Can you update the virtual host configuration? You have `JkMount /* loadbalancer` in your virtual host, so everything is sent to the first two nodes.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz, updated the vhost files for both apps , can you please check .thank you.

Comment: Try `JkMount /app1/* loadbalancer` (with the leading `/`).

Comment: Tried with JkMount /app1/* loadbalancer  and JkMount /app2/* loadbalancer2. But no luck.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz , Any thoughts on this issue ?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz, I made few changes in the v-hosts file . It is working now. 

your previous comment  "You can just put both load balancer definitions into one workers.properties file. Just make sure that the identifiers (the word after workers.) are distinct for the two sets" was helpful to create two loadbalancers for two apps.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Please, write an answer with the configuration that worked.